Would it be possible to cap the output voltage of a Joule Thief using feedback from linear regulator ground pin?
Please bear with me if this is a stupid question, I made about 5 functioning circuits in my life.
I am making a simple tool that beeps when it detects water. I am using attiny13 microprocessor (it's easier for me than building oscillator from scratch), some scrap speaker and MOSFET. I want it to require at most 2 AA batteries. It works fine, but could be a little louder. It also does not work all that well when the batteries are at 2V. I could use Joule Thief, and I am building one now, but I suspect it could raise the voltage too much - as far as I can see it has no feedback and if the resistance on output is high, it will produce high voltage.
If I just add a linear regulator, I will waste all the power I gathered. If I understand it correctly, linear regulator dumps the "extra voltage" to the ground pin. So I wonder, could it be possible to somehow use that pin as a negative feedback to the joule thief, limiting its output? I have some N channel mosfets and NPN transistors, but I can't think of a way to hook them up so that voltage between something and ground stops the joule thief.

How about an amplifier, buffer or just a more sensitive speaker?

The speaker is switched via mosfet - it gets as much voltage as the batteries provide. I added a capacitor after the battery and did not see any difference. The only improvement with current voltage would be using h-bridge to switch the speaker in both directions, but it would require me to reimplement the beeping logic. With single pin, I'd have to allways have the speaker pulled in one direction and that would drain battery.

Seems to me that a zener regulator should be enough. See the Wikipedia article on the Joule Thief:

And just omit the linear regulator and C2, and take the output from C1. Pick the Zener voltage to get what you want (output voltage will be about 0.7V more than the Zener voltage).
But before you try that, try driving your sound transducer push-pull if you've not done that already. You can effectively double the voltage that way.
There are even little Class D amplifiers that you can use:


I've seen that circuit and I am going to try it, but since I cannot find any zener diode, I was looking for a workaround. I am probably not gonna find one during the weekend :( I'll look into the push pull thing. I thought about this, but the only solutions I could think of is h-bridge which would require custom beep algorithm and having it in reverse by default and switch direction when digital pin is up, which would drain battery over the speaker.

You can use LEDs in series to make up a fake Zener.

Heh, wouldn't think of that. With polarity the same way as I'd put up a zener or reverse? How can I figure out how many?

Forward voltage, so the opposite way from a Zener. Green ones are around 2-3V so a couple in series. Red about 1.8 or 2. Blue about 3.

While it may be possible to regulate the output voltage of a Joule Thief, at the end of the day, it may be easier and/or more reliable to implement a boost converter using a boost controller chip that doesn't require much input voltage.
For example, you can implement a boost converter that will output 3.3 V, with an input voltage anywhere between 1.1 and 3.3 V, using the very inexpensive DIO6199BST6. Although the chip is manufactured in China, it is sold by reputable suppliers such as Mouser, so I would trust that (if purchased from a reputable supplier) it performs reliably according to its datasheet.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Since you are fairly new to electronics, be aware that that the switching frequency for this chip is 1 MHz. Layout is therefore important. L1, C1, R1, and R2 should be kept close to the controller chip. The circuit may not run on solderless breadboard.
There are other chips available which could be used for such a converter. Search your electronic components supplier's online database. Most(?) will allow you to select the minimum input voltage of a controller chip.

I do have actually some IC for power supply on that same breadboard where I was attempting to construct the joule thief. I am now investigating if I can use it. It worked as a step down supply, but is supposed to be universal.
